# Failed to authenticate Service Account credential in Google Cloud Prediction API Library for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, authentication, google-prediction

I was using [`googleapis`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) library and successfully authenticate my Service Account credentials using JWT. Then I found out [`google-cloud`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/prediction) library, which has specific modules for Prediction API, but failed to authenticate the same Service Account credentials.

I don't use Google Computing Engine or App Engine and working in local developement

I follow code in documentation:

```
var key = require('./MY_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDENTIALS.json')
var prediction = require('@google-cloud/prediction')({
  projectId: 'MY_PROJECT_ID',
  credentials: key
})

prediction.getModels((err, models) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return
  }

  console.log('Models:', models)
})
```

and it returns:

```
{ ApiError: Access to project denied: user requires read permissions.                                              
    at [here goes stack trace]                                                                                   
  code: 401,                                                                                                       
  errors:                                                                                                          
   [ { domain: 'global',                                                                                           
       reason: 'authError',                                                                                        
       message: 'Access to project denied: user requires read permissions.',                                       
       locationType: 'header',                                                                                     
       location: 'Authorization' } ],                                                                              
  response: undefined,                                                                                             
  message: 'Access to project denied: user requires read permissions.' }
```

I don't know where it goes wrong and I'm not sure if I would need to authenticate with `googleapis` and integrate it with `google-cloud` or etc. It's also lack of samples

Answer (score 1):

So I know this is a couple of months old but the error is pretty self explanatory but I also ran into this issue myself.

Essentially your service key isn't given the proper permissions in order to read (or write) information from your project. Look for your service account under **IAM & Admin** in the Google Cloud Console and add *Project → Editor* and/or *Project → Viewer* to the service account you've created. Make sure you press "Save" once you've added those permissions and wait about 20 seconds for those permissions to reflect.